# Broadcasting an EVENT_REMINDER

Tags: android, events

I am trying to broadcast an EVENT_REMINDER in order to cause the system to popup a notification. Is it possible or do I have to hit the route of implementing a Sync Adapter? That seems too much for such a simple task. I know some broadcasts are protected (CALL, SMS) but this should not be the case.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can display a notification using `NotificationCompat` and `NotificationManager`. What makes you think that sending this broadcast is appropriate and will have the effects that you seek? What makes you think that a `SyncAdapter` has anything to do with any of this?

Comment: I don't want to pop a Notification I want to simulate an event reminder programmatically. I've read on the documentation that you can implement a full calendar in your app through a Sync adapter: that seems too overkill.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to pop a Notification I want to simulate an event reminder programmatically

I have no idea what you think an "event reminder" is that isn't a `Notification` -- every device on which I use the Calendar app, event reminders are `Notifications`. Also, please note that what you claim in your comment runs counter to your first sentence of your question, where you specifically state that you want to "popup a notification":

> I am trying to broadcast an EVENT_REMINDER in order to cause the system to popup a notification.

Regardless, the AOSP calendar app will not respond to your broadcast. From [the manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml), you need to have a `content://` `Uri` in the `Intent`, and presumably that will need to point to an actual calendar entry. And I would not be surprised if devices that replace the AOSP calendar app with their own do not support the broadcast at all.